# NestedScrollView does not scroll. View.canScrollVertically() returns false

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

In my android app I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` which contains a `NestedScrollView` inside which there is an custom class `ImageView` with `onMeasure()` changed.

When I try the code in an independent app in `Activity` the `NestedScrollView` scrolls properly.

But when I integrate the same code in my app's `BottomSheetDialogFragment` it does not scroll and `canScrollVertically()` (both -1 and 1) returns false for `NestedScrollView`.

I set visibility of `content_webview` to `View.GONE` and that of `NestedScrollView` to `View.VISIBLE` when I need to show the `ImageView`. The image forms and loads properly. Problem is `NestedScrollView` does not scroll.

What is wrong with my `layout` file? I haven't disabled scrolling of any sort in the java file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_webview_loading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2.5dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressTint="@color/green"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/lighter_gray_2"
    android:max="100"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    />

<com.hootout.webviews.NestedScrollingWebView
    android:id="@+id/content_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/progress_webview_loading">

</com.hootout.webviews.NestedScrollingWebView>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/pdf_view_scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/progress_webview_loading"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <com.hootout.custom.AspectRatioImageView
        android:id="@+id/pdf_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn_close_content_webview"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/icon_close_without_circle"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button_goto_top"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

AspectRatioImageView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class AspectRatioImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int 
defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    if(getDrawable() != null)
    {
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / 
getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    }
    else{
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was `BottomSheetDialogFragment` **can only host one child** with `nestedScrolling`. In my case I was adding `WebView` and `NestedScrollView`(with `ImageView` inside).

So regardless of whether I set visibility `View.GONE` for `WebView` the scrolling child for `BottomSheetDialogFragment` was always set to `WebView`.

Bottom line. I ended up creating a separate `BottomSheetDialogFragment` for `ImageView` since `BottomSheetDialogFragment` only accepts one scrolling child (the very first one it finds while scanning from top of view hierarchy).

Now everything works fine.